# What is the penalty for not saving enough civilians in a retaliation mission?

Tags: xcom-2

I've been faced with the decision a few times of sacrificing a soldier to make sure I can save a 6th civilian before they all die, and I'm wondering how to weight the pros and cons of that trade. I haven't failed a retaliation mission yet and am wondering what detrimental effects it has.

Comment: I believe it's that you lose that region as a resistance contact. (aka, they're wiped out, need to find a new group of rebels)

Comment: I did not save enough civilians in a retaliation mission in the start region and the penalty was a permanent reduction of the monthly supply drop by 30-something §. Also, in the monthly summary the big boss told me to try harder even though I succeeded in plenty of other important mission. What @RavenDreamer said might apply to a retaliation mission in a different region, but I don't remember that I ever got one.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254526/what-is-the-penalty-for-not-saving-enough-civilians-in-a-retaliation-mission

Answer (score 7):

When you fail to save enough civvies, you lose contact with the resistance in that area, and will have to reestablish contact by scanning the area again. While contact is lost, your radio tower in the area will not be available. Even after contact is reestablished, you suffer a penalty to the amount of supplies they provide per month.