# Ignoring a retaliation site?

Tags: xcom-2

So as far as I can tell the retaliation sites are similar to XCOM: Enemy Unknowns panic missions, being that it was a specific attack on an area.  However they gave the reward of reduced panic if you won, for the retaliation missions in XCOM 2 I can't see any reward before taking them.   Do they have any negative impact if you ignore them?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254526/what-is-the-penalty-for-not-saving-enough-civilians-in-a-retaliation-mission

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignoring a retaliation strike (or as far as I can tell, most missions) will cause the Resistance in that region to "scatter". You will no longer have contacts in that region, and the monthly supply reward they give is permanently reduced if you do make contact with them again. If you have a continent bonus for that continent, you will lose it until you make contact with the region once again.

Comment: Oh so it's a case of if you don't do it, you drop that region?  I wish it was a little more clear in the game - or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You're not missing anything - the negative consequences aren't stated anywhere until you do it. I only found out because I was ignoring every mission at the end of the game so I could hurry up and beat it.